# How to escape to latex within minted comments?

Tags: cross-referencing, minted, shell-escape, fancyvrb

I am using the `minted` package for typesetting matlab source code.

There is an `escapeinside` option for the `listing` environment provided by minted to escape to regular TeX commands.

However, this does not work on comment lines.  Here is a `MWE` illustrating the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The code for computing mass-energy relationship is given in listing~\ref{listing:massenergy}.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:massenergy}
    e = mc^2
\end{equation}
\begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}[mathescape,autogobble,escapeinside=||,frame=single]{matlab}
    e = m*c^2; % |see equation~\eqref{eq:massenergy}| does not work!
    |see equation~\eqref{eq:massenergy}| works
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Mass-Energy source code listing}
    \label{listing:massenergy}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output produced

[image: comments in minted is a problem]

**How can one escape to TeX/LaTeX inside minted comment lines**?

Comment: The documentation about `escapeinside` says “Escaping does not work inside strings and comments (for comments, there is `texcomments`).”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation of `minted` about `escapeinside` says

> **Escaping does not work inside strings and comments (for comments, there is** `texcomments`**).**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The code for computing mass-energy relationship is given
in listing~\ref{listing:massenergy}.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:massenergy}
    e = mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{listing}[htp]
\begin{minted}[frame=single,texcomments]{matlab}
e = m*c^2; % see equation \eqref{eq:massenergy}
\end{minted}
\caption{Mass-Energy source code listing}
\label{listing:massenergy}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed this is the case. I am sorry I missed this. Thank you for pointing this out. Marked the answer as accepted. Thanks again!