# How to escape backticks (any string) to write latex code inside minted block in (lua)latex?

Tags: luatex, unicode, minted

I have seen similar questions ([a](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60155/minted-doesnt-escape-latex-code-inside-python-docstring), [b](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433628/how-to-escape-to-latex-within-minted-comments), [c](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384468/minted-escapeinside-doesnt-work-within-a-string)) but this one is a bit different.

Yesterday I was so excited to start learning latex and quick enough I discovered packages that can render any source code. But in my program, there are some Unicode (multibyte) characters that are not rendered with standard font families. So I used emoji package for this. And soon after that I couldn't render these special characters inside (TypeScript) string which is inside minted block.

Surely I can escape by using the same type of quotes around the latex code inside string: `"string "|\escaped|" string"`, but this will render another pair of quotes in PDF, so this won't work.

AFAIK, I should use another package, but minted is soo good. How can I solve the problem without ditching minted package?

Here is a short example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[cachedir=../.cache, outputdir=output]{minted}
\usepackage{emoji}

\def\done{\emoji{check-mark-button}}

\begin{document}
\noindent It shows here (outside minted) -> \done
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{typescript}
...
hbs.registerHelper("list", function(this: any) {
  ...
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    |It shows here (inside minted) -> \done|
    rows += `
    |But not in here (inside minted and backticks) -> \done|
        ...
      `
  })
  ...
});
...
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

And the output: 
[image]

Comment: Same cause as [italic - Minted escapeinside doesn't work within a string - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384468/minted-escapeinside-doesnt-work-within-a-string) but I don't know how generalizable is the answer because I didn't look at the manual to see what `\PYG` does

Comment: @user202729, yes. But in my case, I have a lot of characters on multiple lines between quotes (backticks) and `escapeinside=||` doesn't seem to work when escape characters (start `|` and end `|`) are placed on different lines.

Comment: `escapeinside` comments and strings is a GitHub issue, according to the documentation.

Comment: @Cicada, can you provide a link to the issue? I can't find it (or the issue covers a slightly different problem).

Comment: `minted` doc p24 links to: [GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/70#issuecomment-111729930)

Comment: Might be unrelated, but for reference: "'fancyvrb’ print[s] a line only after finding it[s] end character" (fancyvrb-doc.pdf, p6), that is, a comment character hides the line-end character. Note also that `fvextra` package does some patching - I don't know if it affects multilines, but probably not since the closing back tick (and colour) is applied to the first line only.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're after, but how about this?

An indirect (=meta) command for the backtick (grave accent), option1; or mixing in some Pygment metacommands, option2.

[image: back tick]

In both cases, the special character is "hidden" from the lexer, and is inserted "manually", so to speak.

Fonts and red colour arbitrarily chosen for demonstration purposes for 1 and 2. Option 3 is the minted colour scheme.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\fsym{Noto Sans Symbols2}
\newfontface\fsymb{Noto Emoji}
\def\done{{\fsym ☑✓✔}{\fsymb ✅}}

%Adapted from
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384468/minted-escapeinside-doesnt-work-within-a-string:
\newcommand{\metastring}[1]{\PYG{l+s}{\Uchar96}\PYG{l+s}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}\PYG{l+s}{\Uchar96}}
\newcommand{\metastringb}[1]{\PYG{l+s}{\Uchar96}\PYG{l+s}{#1}\PYG{l+s}{\Uchar96}}



\begin{document}
\noindent It shows here (outside minted) -> \done
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{typescript}
...
hbs.registerHelper("list", function(this: any) {
  ...
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    |It shows here (inside minted) -> \done|
    rows += |\Uchar96|
    |{\color{red}1. But not in here (inside minted and backticks) -> \done}|
    |\Uchar96|
        ...
     
    |\metastring{2. But not in here (inside minted and backticks) -> \done}|
    
    |\metastringb{3. But not in here (inside minted and backticks) -> \done}|
      
  })
  ...
});
...
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The big problem that I encountered, after trying using several methods (and including this one), is that the coloring is not applied to things such as `\`${this}\`` (putting variables inside interpolated string).